# ImportError: cannot import name 'ProcessPoolExecutor' from 'concurrent.futures.process'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, concurrent.futures

I have a problem that I cannot figure out what happened:
I was trying to follow a multiprocessing tutorial using the following code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something(seconds):
    print(f'sleeping {seconds} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return 'Done sleeping'

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(do_something, 1)
    print(f1.result())
```

I ran this piece of code successfully in jupyter notebook but got the following error message when I ran it in Pycharm:

```
/Users/jiangxu/PycharmProjects/Assign_compartment/venv/bin/python /Users/jiangxu/PycharmProjects/Assign_compartment/multiprocessing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jiangxu/PycharmProjects/Assign_compartment/multiprocessing.py", line 14, in <module>
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 43, in __getattr__
    from .process import ProcessPoolExecutor as pe
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 53, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "/Users/jiangxu/PycharmProjects/Assign_compartment/multiprocessing.py", line 14, in <module>
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 43, in __getattr__
    from .process import ProcessPoolExecutor as pe
ImportError: cannot import name 'ProcessPoolExecutor' from 'concurrent.futures.process' (/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/process.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

so what happened?

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same problem. It is because the name of the python file is "multiprocessing" so what you have to do is just change that.

Comment: Also if the name is threading.py, it gives error. Any idea why that is the case?